# Ubuntu touch on a Medion Lifetab E10320 possible?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

This is a long shot since my tablet is not listed in the supported devices, but is there any chance that it might work anyway?

Android 4.2
Tablet E10320

Comment: No, not a chance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work at the moment. You could look at porting Ubuntu Touch for your device if you were interested.

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/